# How to Handle HTTP Basic Auth headers in Selenium Webdriver using Java ?

Tags: java, selenium

How to handle **Http Basic Auth headers** in **Selenium Web-driver** using Java?
I used this format `**driver.get("http://username:password@url.com/login")**` 
to handle Http basic Authentication when Authentication dialog appears first time  but it prompt again after Website Login request submitted to server but the Approach i used earlier is not working after Login Scenario.

Help would really Appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try This .....

```
     try{ 
        String webPage = "http://www.domain.com/";
        String Uname = "admin";
        String password = "admin";

        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Where is Selenium being used in the answer?

Comment: And why is it accepted as an answer? It's not an answer to the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Alert.authenticateUsing(Credentials)`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#authenticateUsing-org.openqa.selenium.security.Credentials-) to handle the authentication dialog:

```
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

Answer (score 0):

With [BrowserMob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium) you can create a proxy which sets the Authentication Header to the request.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
    <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Start the Proxy and configure the webdriver

```
public static WebDriver getWebdriver() {
    BrowserMobProxyServer proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();

    // Adds Filter to manipulate the request header
    proxy.addRequestFilter((request, contents, messageInfo) -> {
        // Create the Base64 String for authorization
        String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("user:password");
        // Set the Authorization header to the request
        request.headers().add("Authorization", authHeader);
        return null;
    });
    proxy.start(0);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    // Get the Selenium proxy object
    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
    // To manipulate requests for local host
    seleniumProxy.setNoProxy("<-loopback>");
    options.setProxy(seleniumProxy);
    // Initialize the webdriver with the proxy settings
    return new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

To stop the proxy simply call

```
proxy.stop();
```