# How to disable the authentication popup in chrome browser while running Selenium Script

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, security, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLMFT.png)Through first URL, I click on login (as shown in Image) which leads to another URL where I need to enter the credentials. But before that page I see a pop up generated from the browser which cannot be located by Selenium. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rDeq.png). The version of my chrome browser is Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I tried using the following methods:

1. Alert.dismiss()
2. JavaScript

   ```
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return
   ```

   true; }");
3. AutoIt

   ```
   WinWaitActive("Windows Security")
   Send("admin{TAB}")
   Send("Password{Enter}")
   ```
4. Robot class

   ```
   alert.sendKeys("UserName");
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
   alert.sendKeys("Password");
   alert.accept();
   ```
5. Also tried to navigate through second URL by entering the Username and Password within the URL

Along with this also used some of the Chrome options in my selenium script

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 


ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities); 


WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

Is there any other way to remove this popup within chrome settings or through script?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What error message you are getting? And which language you are working on? AutoIt should have resolved your problem.

WinWaitActive("Windows Security") 
Send("admin") 
Send("{TAB}")
Send("Password")
Send("{ENTER}")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Other way to basic authenticate than via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-other-way-to-basic-authenticate-than-via-url)

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar : I'm not getting any error. I'm working in JAVA. All my scripts get passed in Firefox (except for some functionality which is supported by Chrome)

My Actual problem is on My second screen I'm getting an authentication popup in chrome browser which I need to Cancel Manually to continue with other part of the script

Comment: @DebanjanB : I tried that configuration also. It didn't serve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Following code working for me

```
    Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable basic authentications using a policy. Create a file called `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/noauth.json` with this content:

```
{
    "AuthSchemes": "negotiate"
}
```

Note: if you are using chromium the directory will be `chromium` or `chromium-browser` instead of `chrome`.