# Close popup in chrome while dom is getting loaded

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, selenium, popup

I am using the latest version of selenium web driver and google chrome browser. 
In my app, after clicking on login button while dom is getting loaded I get a popup

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iFge.png)

I just want to close this popup without entering any value. I am using java for scripting.
I tried javascript executor, all popup handlers from selenium but not able to close the same. I am not able to shift control on the popup window.

I google a lot but didn't found any relevant code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Other way to basic authenticate than via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-other-way-to-basic-authenticate-than-via-url)

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks for reference.

I am using post method for URL and my URL is like https://abcs.def.com/admin
Though I tried it didn't work. still, I am getting the popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using AutoID was able to resolve above issue.

Refernce: http://learn-automation.com/handle-windows-authentication-using-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behavior when using HTTP basic authentication. To stop this window to come you would need to send user and password in the request. Or as I understand from other response I found about this you can write:

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

There seems to be a similar issue, going on in thread: [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is "Cancel" the popup, instead of entering credentials.  You may be able to just use this.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```