# How to handle browser login popup using Selenium & Java

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, popup, alert

The website that I am trying to automate has a authentication popup that appears when someone visits it. I tried the following code but Chrome immediately throws no alert present exception on the `switchTo()` line.

Firefox does not seem to be working. I am currently using Selenium 3.6.0 with the latest binaries of these browsers. Can someone please help me out?

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://staging.brightsociety.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

http://staging.brightsociety.com

[image: authentication required]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Other way to basic authenticate than via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-other-way-to-basic-authenticate-than-via-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium do not handle it by switchto command because this is something that is browser specific instead of website.

Solution 1:

driver.get("http://username:password@url.com");

But problem with this method is that as you traverse to multiple pages the popup will appear again and again which is again difficult to handle.

Solution 2: (Recommended)

AutoIt script, Download AutoIt [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)
And Find the Script for Authentication PopUp [here](https://automationtestingsimplified.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/how-to-handle-window-based-pop-up-using-selenium-and-autoit/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need check it or pass it?
If you need to pass, put login and password in URL.

```
http://username:password@your-web-site.com
```