# How to Close a popup in Selenium that appear after trying to close the browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm facing a problem with my selenium tests.
I have a script that do some stuff and then close the browser
When i do close the browser there is a popup message (screen shot attached) that I need to accept in order for the browser to close.
My problem is that I tried many different idea but none worked. from switch.accept to dismiss() to javascriptExecutor an no luck.
This is the method Im using to close the broswer. after this method is called then i get the popup than i need to close.

```
public static void closeDriver() throws InterruptedException{
     if(driver!=null){
        driver.quit();
        driver=null;
        log.info("The Browser was closed successfully");
    }
```

Comment: I cannot see any screenshot attached. Can you please attach it again?

Comment: I'm not sure how to attach the screen shot after a posting this but here is a link to an exact similar popup to mine:
https://www.google.com/search?q=leave+page+stay+on+page+popup+selenium&client=firefox-b-1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI7_XMudjaAhVJdt8KHWs-C0sQ_AUIDCgD&biw=1536&bih=767#imgrc=AvlMzX2lzgT8lM:

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is little bit complex , as after closing the browser you want to interact with pop up.

Well your code :

```
if(driver!=null){
        driver.quit();
        driver=null;
        log.info("The Browser was closed successfully");
    }
```

your driver instance would be closed after `driver.quit();` line.

```
driver=null;
log.info("The Browser was closed successfully");
```

should not be executed at all.

But if there are multiple instances of browser you've opened to do your testing, you may wanna switch to `driver.close();` .and then try to handle the alert.

Comment: Yep exactly, the issue is that after closing the broswer then i have to interact with the popup, and it's too late there cause i called driver.quit() method. Even if i dont set driver =null it still wont work cause i already called that close method. Also, driver.close() doesnt work . Thanks for the reply though, I appreciate it.

Comment: I do have a workaround by using .vbs file to kill browser process instead of driver.close() but i dont want to use it.I want to see if there is any solution for it

Answer (score 0):

This pop-up cannot be handled with any of selenium commands because it cannot be inspected. You will have to use AutoIt script for that. See the reference below which is for the authentication popup of browser

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47175309/7030563