# Jmeter windows authentication webdriver sampler

Tags: selenium, jmeter

How can I use Windows authentication in jmeter?
I am trying to execute a selenium script in JMeter using WebDriver sampler. I tried HTTP Authorization Manager, it did not worked.

1. Enter the CRM website URL
2. Prompt for windows authentication (username and password)
3. Login to the website and need to perform some user actions .

Windows authentication worked fine in selenium using autoit,same script is not working in jmeter webdriver sampler

Comment: since you are using Selenium / WebDriver Sampler, is really about how to deal with Windows Authentication in Selenium. HTTP Authorization Manager has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: I.E. browser Windows authentication in selenium is handled thru autoit script , Iam trying to use the same code,it is not recognized in jmeter. Runtime.getruntime().execute("autoitscript.exe")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Other way to basic authenticate than via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-other-way-to-basic-authenticate-than-via-url)

Comment: Autoit is only one of the methods mentioned in that question. I'm not sure why someone would use it but did you try simpler methods, such as `driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");`

Comment: Yes, i tried the simple method, it did not work.

Comment: "did not work" is not a definition of the problem we can help with: how it did not work? did you try running this method with selenium outside of JMeter? did that work? if not, then it has nothing to do with JMeter. If it works, then jmeter failure and relevant logs are needed to understand the problem