# How to handle login pop up window using Selenium WebDriver that has @ in password?

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to the site that has windows authentication enabled using URL "http://userName:pass@siteName.com" in selenium web driver. It is working fine in normal cases, however it doesn't work when the password contains a special character **'@'**.

I also tried to handle it using alert with following code, but it is also not working:

```
UserAndPassword up = new UserAndPassword("userName", "pass");
driver.switchTo().alert.authenticateUsing(up);
```

Please suggest how to escape this special character.

I am running my test cases in chrome browser.

Comment: you can use `cntlm` instead of doing the authentication in address, or is that a must?

Comment: I am not aware of cntlm. I am scripting using JAVA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Other way to basic authenticate than via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-other-way-to-basic-authenticate-than-via-url)