# How to Handle Browser Authentication Popup(Corporate web policy) using Selenium Webdriver in Google Chrome?

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, automation

Does anyone know how to handle the browser authentication popup(corporate web policy) using selenium webdriver in google chrome?
Note: I am using Linux-Cent OS 7.
I tried using the "http://username:password@example.com/yourpage", and automating using AutoIT, but since it is linux OS, AutoIt doesnt work.
No error logs are generated.

Details are as follows: 
OS: Linux - Cent OS-7.
Google Chrome version: 62
Selenium-Java version: 3.9.0

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before applying it to a question. The "linux" tag doesn't belong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url)

Comment: The above link which is mentioned as "possible duplicate", doesn't help me out, I have already tried the things mentioned in its Answers.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know how to handle the browser authentication popup with Chrome (In my case, I am using Chrome 63).
I could solve it with Firefox:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://<host>:<port>/<something>')
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.send_keys('<username>' + Keys.TAB + '<password>')
alert.accept()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```