# How to handle browser Authentication for intranet sites in Chrome browser using Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to handle Browser authentication popup in Chrome using Selenium with C#. 
The problem is that , this is not alert so i could switch to it and its not even windows popup which i could have handled using AutoIt.

Kindly suggest options what can be done.

[image: authentication required]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url)

Comment: Can anyone please suggest something on this to handle this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(username).Perform();
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(password).Perform();
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: Did not work . Browser does not move mouse when it gets the browser window open

Comment: Did you try switching to alert first ?

Comment: Selenium is not considering it as an alert.