# Selenium WebDriver.get() gets stuck when the page it is loading is empty with alert popup login

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I have a page that I need to test with selenium, it recently has been changed to use alert popup authentication (If you don't know what I'm talking about then check [this](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/handle-authentication-popup-window/).

My current approach is pretty much 3. approach from the link above, but I use Actions to send keys instead of just finding elements.

```
browser.get(url)
Alert alert = browser.switchTo().alert();
Actions action = new Actions(browser)
action.sendkeys(user).sendkeys(Keys.tab).sendkeys(password).perform()
alert.accept()
```

the problem starts right at the first line, it gets stuck there... Seems like selenium/chromedriver doesn't detect that page is loaded and it can proceed to next line.

I know this for sure because when I try to print something after first line, it never get printed and eventually (an eternity later) it throws me TimeOutException.

Any suggestions?

Using latest:
Selenium 3.11.0
ChromeDriver 2.38
Google Chrome 66

Comment: Could you please try with - driver.navigate().to() in place of driver.get()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url)

Comment: @PritamM.Maske I tried that, didn't work... Same issues

Comment: @DebanjanB Well I didn't try to authenticate with url because it doesn't work on chrome... So I don't think this is the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pop-up is not a part of browser, it belongs to OS, that's why is not accessible via selenium

just put your credentials direct to URL, see [Automating Authentication popup in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283307/automating-authentication-popup-in-selenium/50294466#50294466)

Comment: Yes, totally forgot about this issue I raised on stackoverflow... I found out that what you say is 100% complete true. You can break the timeout chromedriver gives you and regain control, but selenium/chromedriver will still not detect this authentication popup as alert popup because it is not...

I will mark this as an answer and below are a workaround I've discovered (could not use direct url to login, because it was not implemented to our test website).

Workaround: Before triggering authentication popup, you make a separate thread and invoke robot to type login and password