# Automating Authentication popup in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, autoit

I am struggling a bit while automating an authentication pop up in the chrome browser. 
I am using this test site named "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"

Here is my code.

```
public class Authen {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Sumedha\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Selenium\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Sumedha\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Selenium\\AutoIT\\handleauthentication.exe");   
    }
}
```

This is how my autoIT script looks.

```
WinWaitActive("Sign in")
Send("admin")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("admin")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Now when I run this, credentials are not entered in the popup and script does not run at all.

Please help !

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: Use driver.get("http://username:password@http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url)

Comment: @DebanjanB. Link was really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

as cruisepandey writes, only Basic Authentication credentials can be added direct into the url

where as some credential alerts are not browser's component, but OS's.

those pop-ups are not accessible via selenium, a malware could penetrate if it would be possible.

BasicAuthentication put your credentials direct to URL: `https://{username}:{password}@host.com`

OAuth with Manually entered Credentials need a UIAutoamtion based tool, some examples: [AutoIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283307/automating-authentication-popup-in-selenium/50294466#50294466) or [Python uiautomation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825959/6345724).