# Logging to a site through a popup window using SeleniumWeb driver

Tags: java, selenium, authentication

So I am trying to login to a site that has it's first login through a popup window, as soon as you visit it, it brings a popup window that requires a User name and password. Now i have a very rough idea on how i would do this if it wasn't a pop up window, but because I don't know how to see the HTML code of the window, i don't know what to put in to  driver.findElement(By.id("")) .

Sorry in advance if this is all too vague .

Comment: Navigate to the site by yourself. Press F12 to see source-code and IDs of the elements. Create your test with a little timeout (for waiting that the window appears) and go for it.

Comment: Since the pop up window is the first thing when I visit the site, f12 still shows the source code for the chrome "New tab" window

Comment: When you are opening the URL using driver.get(" ") ,then you are getting the pop up ?

Comment: String URL = "http://" + username + ":" + Password + "@" + www.your websitename.com;
driver.get(URL);  try this

Comment: Yep, first thing that happens when I open the url

Comment: For what you recommended above, i get a firefox page that says the connection to the website was reset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url)

Comment: Might be useful to mention that the site has 2 logins, the first one is the popup window, and when that is filled in correctly, then there is another login page before moving to the actual site, don't know if that makes a difference regarding the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not a pop-up, its basic authentication.

Currently, selenium doesn't support basic HTTP authentication ([link to issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/34)), but there are workarounds.

In Chrome driver and Firefox driver, you can insert your username and password in the URL.

Example:
If you have URL like this: http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth

Where username and passwords are both 'admin'

Just change your URL to:

http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth

Java code example:

```
String username = "admin";
String password = "admin";
String url= "http://" + username + ":" + password + "@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth";
driver.get(url);
```

This will automatically handle basic auth in chrome and firefox drivers.

More here: [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url)

Comment: Thank you , but I get a firefox page saying connection was reset

Comment: What version of FF you use?
Also, what version of webdriver and firefox driver?
And is this http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth also gives you same connection was reset as in your app?

Comment: Also, are you getting same problem manually, when trying to paste this url in browser?
Or just when running tests in selenium?

Comment: For firefox i use 60.0 (64-bit) . FirefoxDriver geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64 . And I think its Selenium 3.11.0  . Also when i paste the URL with the username and password to the browser, i get the same problem

Comment: Do you get same issue with example url I gave you? 
http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth
Or just with your url?
Trying to findout if its specific to your app or environment,
also, can you share your url?

Comment: I can login to your URL just fine. Unfortunately i can't share the URL, apologies

Comment: Ok, so now we know its not environment, its your app.
Are you getting this "Connection was reset" when entering username and password manually?

Are you getting it when you navigate to user:pass@your url manually, using selenium, or both?
Are you getting it in chrome too, or just in firefox?

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.
BTW. You may ask your developers to whitelist your IP, so you don't even need to do basic auth to access your site

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the open windows (including the popup) and switch to the desired one (the popup in your case). After that you can use selectors to find the desired elements and enter the login credentials.

Example:

```
WebDriver driver = ...    

String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

String popupWindowHandle = null;
Iterator<String> iterator = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    popupWindowHandle = iterator.next();
}

driver.switchTo().window(popupWindowHandle);
```

Comment: using the names would be better than iterate through windows/elements.

Comment: Thanks, but i have gotten as far as switching to the popup window. I don't know how to find the element's id,name etc to use the selectors

Comment: You can use `driver.getPageSource()` to get the current source of the page. Then you could print it out and search in that code for the desired ids, tags, etc.

Comment: As I said, the popup is the first thing that happens when I visit the site, the rest is blank, so getPageSource() returns <html><head></head><body></body></html>
null

Comment: @Angelos you sure its pop up and not auth alert?

Comment: @Angelos is that pop up window looks somethinf like the one here? http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, it's exactly like that, sry, i didn't know that an auth alert was something different

Comment: @Angelos I posted an answer with code example that should work for you