# How to handle Login authentication pop-up using selenium on chrome browser

Tags: selenium

The pop-up which is highlighted in the image is getting handled on firefox and IE browser as the text of the pop-up gets changed (i.e. it becomes to "Authentication required") but on chrome, it is seen as it is there in the image.
For solving this, i have already used Robot class and AutoIt script, but it is not working.
Is there any other [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3jfZ.png)way to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url)

Comment: try this :  String URL = "http://" + username + ":" + Password + "@" + www.your websitename.com; driver.get(URL);